# How to read csv file into List<List<Object>> with CSVHelper

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I have this data in a text/csv file:

```
ID,Boo,Soo
0,True,qwerty
0,True,qwerty

0,True,qwerty
0,True,qwerty

0,True,qwerty
0,True,qwerty
0,True,qwerty

0,True,qwerty
0,True,qwerty
0,True,qwerty
0,True,qwerty

0,True,qwerty
0,True,qwerty
0,True,qwerty
0,True,qwerty
```

Note especially the blank lines. I want to use `CSVHelper` from NuGet to read this data into multiple lists, where the boundary is determined by the blank lines.

So if have a class `MyClass` with an properties, `ID`, `Boo`, and `Soo`, and I were to initialize the sample data above in code directly, I'd want a `List<List<Mycass>>` like this:

```
var data = {
    new List<MyClass> {
        { new MyClass {ID = 0, Boo = true, Soo = "qwerty"} },
        { new MyClass {ID = 0, Boo = true, Soo = "qwerty"} }
    },
    new List<MyClass> {
        { new MyClass {ID = 0, Boo = true, Soo = "qwerty"} },
        { new MyClass {ID = 0, Boo = true, Soo = "qwerty"} }
    },
    new List<MyClass> {
        { new MyClass {ID = 0, Boo = true, Soo = "qwerty"} },
        { new MyClass {ID = 0, Boo = true, Soo = "qwerty"} },
        { new MyClass {ID = 0, Boo = true, Soo = "qwerty"} }
    },
    new List<MyClass> {
        { new MyClass {ID = 0, Boo = true, Soo = "qwerty"} },
        { new MyClass {ID = 0, Boo = true, Soo = "qwerty"} },
        { new MyClass {ID = 0, Boo = true, Soo = "qwerty"} },
        { new MyClass {ID = 0, Boo = true, Soo = "qwerty"} }
    },
    new List<MyClass> {
        { new MyClass {ID = 0, Boo = true, Soo = "qwerty"} },
        { new MyClass {ID = 0, Boo = true, Soo = "qwerty"} },
        { new MyClass {ID = 0, Boo = true, Soo = "qwerty"} },
        { new MyClass {ID = 0, Boo = true, Soo = "qwerty"} }
    },
}
```

But, of course, I don't know in advance what the data will really look like. I don't know how many entries need to go in each list, and I don't know how many lists I'll need. There could be any random number of items in each list between the blank lines.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
for (int j = 0; j < rnd.Next(4, 10); j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rnd.Next(1, 7); i++)
    {
        ListMyClass.Add(new MyClass { ID = 0, Boo = true, Soo = "qwerty" });
    }

    ListListMyClass.Add(new List<MyClass>(ListMyClass));
    ListMyClass.Clear();
}

using (var csvWiter = new CsvWriter(new StreamWriter("csvHelper.csv"), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
{
    foreach (var listRecord in ListListMyClass)
    {
        csvWiter.WriteRecords(listRecord);
        csvWiter.NextRecord();
    }
}

//this code reads all objects, but that's wrong.
using (var reader = new StreamReader("csvHelper.csv"))
            using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
            {
                var list = csv.GetRecords<MyClass>().ToList();
                ;
            }
```

How can I do this?

EDIT:
I solved it with solution from Michael Jones. Thanks.

Other solution:

```
csvReader.Configuration.IgnoreBlankLines = false;
while (csvReader.Read())
            {
                if (csvReader.Context.Record.IsEmpty())
                {
                    ListListMyClass.Add(new List<MyClass>(ListObject));
                    ListMyClass.Clear();
                    continue;
                }
                ListMyClass.Add(csvReader.GetRecord<MyClass>());
            }
```

Thank you

Comment: where is the code that tries to read from the csv file? What exactly is the nature of your problem when reading the file? please don't say that your problem is that you don't have the code.

Comment: you don't need List of List here:``ListListMyClass``. add simple new list ``NewListMyClass`` and replace ``ListListMyClass.Add(new List<MyClass>(ListMyClass));`` with ``NewListMyClass.AddRange(ListMyClass);`` and read it in your forrach OR use ``SelectMany`` in your list ``ListListMyClass``

Comment: You said you wanna read, but your code is trying to write, which one is correct? Also, when you do `ListMyClass.Clear();` you're erasing everything you have done.

Comment: @Magnetron, he adds ``ListMyClass`` in ``ListListMyClass`` before clear it.

Comment: @Sajid Oh, he adds as a new List, ok then.

Comment: thanks guys for editing my post.

Comment: @ČernýAdam CSV is a poor file format choice for this data. If you have a choice about the file format type, I would use something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll add another option that is a little more dependent on `CsvHelper`.

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{        
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    using (CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        writer.WriteLine("ID,Boo,Soo");
        writer.WriteLine("0,True,\"Test\nqwerty\"");
        writer.WriteLine("0,True,qwerty");
        writer.WriteLine("");
        writer.WriteLine("0,True,qwerty");
        writer.Flush();
        stream.Position = 0;

        csv.Configuration.IgnoreBlankLines = false;

        csv.Read();
        csv.ReadHeader();

        var data = new List<List<MyClass>>();
        var resultSet = new List<MyClass>();

        while (csv.Read())
        {
            if (csv.Context.RawRecord.Trim() == string.Empty)
            {
                data.Add(resultSet);
                resultSet = new List<MyClass>();
                continue;
            }

            var record = csv.GetRecord<MyClass>();

            resultSet.Add(record);
        }
        if (resultSet.Count > 0)
        {
            data.Add(resultSet);
        }
    } 
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is use an iterator block to provide separate streams that break between blank lines:

```
public IEnumerable<TextReader> ReadSeparatedFile(string filePath)
{
     using (var rdr = new StreamReader(filePath))
     {
          string line = rdr.ReadLine();
          while(line is object)
          {
              var buffer = new StringBuilder();
              do
              {
                  if (line != string.Empty) buffer.AppendLine(line);
                  line = rdr.ReadLine();
              } while (line is object && line != string.Empty())
              yield return new StringReader(buffer.ToString());
          }
     }
}
```

Now you can call this method and have a sequence of streams for the `CsvReader`:

```
var data = ReadSeparatedFile("csvHelper.csv");
var result = new List<List<MyClass>>();
foreach(var stream in data)
{
    using (var rdr = new CsvReader(stream))
    {
        result.Add(rdr.GetRecords<MyClass>());
    }
}
```

Not being personally familiar with how the `CsvReader` type maps csv columns to object fields, you may or may not also want to inject the header row into each sequence. But we can do that by adding only one line of code and changing one other:

```
public IEnumerable<TextReader> ReadSeparatedFile(string filePath)
{
     using (var rdr = new StreamReader(filePath))
     {
          string header = rdr.ReadLine() + "\n";
          string line = rdr.ReadLine();
          while(line is object)
          {
              var buffer = new StringBuilder(header);
              do
              {
                  if (line != string.Empty) buffer.AppendLine(line);
                  line = rdr.ReadLine();
              } while (line is object && line != string.Empty())
              yield return new StringReader(buffer.ToString());
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: I had to change the line `var buffer = new StringBuilder(header);` to `var buffer = new StringBuilder().AppendLine(header);` in order to get it to work.

Comment: @DavidSpecht Strange,  you should be able to use this constructor overload: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Text_StringBuilder__ctor_System_String_

Comment: The problem is it doesn't include a line break when you add it that way, so the header and the next line end up on a single line.

Comment: @DavidSpecht Ah, of course. I should have seen that. Fixed now in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

well reading the doc at: https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/api/CsvHelper/CsvReader
you will need to call `csv.GetRecord<MyClass>();` to get one record(line) of the CSV
and `csv.Read()` to set the Reader to the next Row. However please consider using properly formatted files in the future.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I don't think you should be creating a CSV file like this. Can you use another format, such as JSON? Look into `Newtonsoft.Json` for serializing/deserializing JSON. CSV is a poor file format choice for something like this.

Having said that, this will do the trick, as ugly as it feels. (You will have to decorate your model with the CSV index, unless you know how to set the header manually. I haven't looked into the library that deeply).

```cs
void Main()
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\temp\csvHelper.csv"))
    {
        IEnumerable<IEnumerable<MyClass>> setOfSets = ReadCSVCollection<MyClass>(reader);
    }
}

public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> ReadCSVCollection<T>(StreamReader reader, bool hasHeader = true)
{
    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
    string header = hasHeader ? reader.ReadLine() : null;

    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        string line = reader.ReadLine();
        if (line.Trim() == string.Empty)
        {
            yield return ReadCSVString<T>(buffer.ToString());
            buffer = new StringBuilder();
            continue;
        }
        buffer.AppendLine(line);
    }

    yield return ReadCSVString<T>(buffer.ToString());
}

public static IEnumerable<T> ReadCSVString<T>(string input, bool hasHeader = false)
{
    using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(input))
    using (CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(sr, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = hasHeader;
        return csv.GetRecords<T>().ToList();
    }
}


public class MyClass
{
    [CsvHelper.Configuration.Attributes.Index(0)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [CsvHelper.Configuration.Attributes.Index(1)]
    public bool Boo { get; set; }
    [CsvHelper.Configuration.Attributes.Index(2)]
    public string Soo { get; set; }
}

// Define other methods and classes here
```

Comment: The only issue I see now is it will fail if `Soo` contains a line break.

Comment: @DavidSpecht You're right; my edit should account for that. I would still advocate not using CSV for this.

Comment: Yes, your edit appears to have fixed the line break issue and I agree on not advocating on using CSV for this format.

Comment: @DavidSpecht In terms of sticking to the library, I like your answer more - I was too lazy to actually dig into the library though..

Answer (score 0):

Another option: using [SoftCircuits.CsvParser](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SoftCircuits.CsvParser/), your code would look something like this:

```
List<List<MyClass>> data = new List<List<MyClass>>();

using (CsvDataReader<MyClass> reader = new CsvDataReader<MyClass>(path))
{
    reader.ReadHeaders(true);

    data.Add(new List<MyClass>());
    while (reader.Read(out MyClass item))
    {
        if (reader.ColumnCount == 0)
            data.Add(new List<MyClass>());
        else
            data[data.Count - 1].Add(item);
    }
}
```

My testing showed SoftCircuits.CsvParser to average about four times faster than CsvHelper.